# Is this a valid proof for the divergence of $E\left( \frac{1}{\bar{X}} \right)$ for a Normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

I have come across this proof and I was wondering if it is valid. What troubles me is the inequality $e^{-\frac{n}{2} \theta^2} > \frac{1}{2}$ as it's not obvious to me how one gets there. I know that $e^{-x} \geq 1-x$ but other than that I am stuck.

[image]

All help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For each $n$ you need a different $ε$, otherwise I does not seem to work. In other words $ε$ is $ε(n)$.

Comment: @JimmyR. I believe $n$ is kept fixed so this is not a problem.

Comment: $E(\frac 1 X)$ diverges for any $X$ that has positive density at in the neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since $e^{-x}\ge 1-x$ (as you pointed), for fixed $n$ and $0<θ<ε$ you know that $$e^{-\frac{n}{2}θ^2}>e^{-\frac{n}{2}ε^2}\ge 1-\frac{n}{2}ε^2$$ where the first inequality is due to the monotonicity of the exponential function. So, if you could show that $1-\frac{n}{2}ε^2\ge \frac12$ the proof would be valid. You have that $$1-\frac{n}{2}ε^2\overset{?}\ge \frac12 \iff nε^2\overset{?}\le 1$$ but since $n$ is fixed and $0<ε$ is arbitrarily small (or "sufficiently small" as the author of the proof indicates) then this holds for any $ε\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Oh I see it now. The $1/2$ is arbitrary, we could have chosen $1/3$ or anything else.

Comment: @JohnK Yes, exactly. I guess he only chooses $1/2$ for simplicity in his proof.

Comment: Usually a downvote comes with an explanation of the mistake, so I (and perhaps also the OP) am waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What is $$\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0} e^{-\frac{n}{2}\theta^2}?$$

What does this tell us about when $\theta$ is sufficiently small?

Comment: It tells us that this will be very close to $1$ but where does the $1/2$ come from?

Comment: @JohnK By definition, this means that if I choose $\epsilon$ small enough, then for all  $|\theta| < \epsilon, |e^{-(n/2)\theta^2} - 1| < 1/2$ i.e. $e^{-(n/2)\theta^2 } > 1/2$.

Comment: That's great, thank you.